# Use Android binding in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build an app with Xamarin.Forms. I want to use Google ML Kit, so I found a binding for Android.

I was able to import the reference into the Android part of the Xamarin.Forms solution and would like to use it in the code behind the UI.

But in the `in` project, when I do `using Xamarin.Firebase.ML.Vision;` I get an error of course, because the reference is in the `in.Android` project. Am I trying to do something that is anti-pattern in Xamarin?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxO5C.png]

Comment: use a Custom Renderer or DependencyService to use platform specific code in XF.   Both are documented on the Xamarin site

Comment: just to give you a heads up, Firebase.ML and Firebase ML Kit are two different libraries. see this issue on github. the short of it is the android library covers only Firebase.ML(cloud based machine learning) and not ML Kit(which is for on device machine learning). See [here](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/359). the bindings library i linked in my answer for iOS seems to be ML Kit, but there is no android equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Xamarin.Firebase.ML.Vision` is a `Xamarin.Android` specific library. it doesn't exist for `Xamarin.Forms`. As mentioned you need to use the `DependencyService` to spin up a platform specific implementation. In this case, an `Activity` that implements the `Xamarin.Firebase.ML.Vision` code you need.

```
public interface IVisionImplementer
{
    void StartActivity();
}
```

Then in your `Xamarin.Android` project.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(VisionImplementer))]
public class VisionImplementer : IVisionImplementer
{
    public void StartActivity()
    {
        ///FirebaseActivity is where you will implement the actual vision code you're trying to implement.
        var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(FirebaseVisionActivity))
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

To use from `Xamarin.Forms` use:

```
var visionImplementer = DependencyService.Get<IVisionImplementer>();
visionImplementer.StartActivity();
```

That's it. There is also [library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.MLKit.Vision/) for iOS so you can do the same thing for your iOS project.